# Does the inequality $\mathrm{tr}(L^\dagger L \rho^2)-\mathrm{tr}(L^\dagger \rho L\rho )\geq 0$ hold generally?

Tags: quantum-state, density-matrix, linear-algebra

Does the inequality
$$\mathrm{tr}(L^\dagger L \rho^2)-\mathrm{tr}(L^\dagger \rho L\rho )\geq 0$$
hold for any density matrix $\rho$ and any non-Hermitian Lindblad operator $L$?

Comment: What conditions are imposed on a Lindbladian operator?

Comment: To follow up, if you just naively apply Cauchy-Schwarz you find that $\mathrm{tr}[L^\dagger \rho L \rho] \leq \mathrm{tr}[\sqrt{\rho L^\dagger L \rho}]$ and the latter quantity can be expressed in terms of the eigenvalues of $L^\dagger L \rho^2$ which appears in your question. In particular if all the eigenvalues of the latter operator are larger than $1$ then your result would follow from Cauchy Schwarz as then $\sqrt{\rho L^\dagger L \rho} \leq \rho L^\dagger L \rho$. However, if there are no additional restrictions on $L$ (it is just non-Hermitian) then the result is not true.

Comment: $\rho=\sum^N_{i=1}\lambda_i|\phi_i><\phi_i|$ is the $N\times N$  density matrix, where $\lambda_i$ and $|\phi_i>$ are the i-th eigenvalue and  i-th component state, respectively. $L$ is the $N\times N$ Lindblad operator operator representing the decoherence process. No conditions are imposed on $L$, except for $N\times N$.

Comment: Are you saying that $L$ can be *any* $N \times N$ matrix?

Comment: Yes. I consider that $\rho$ obeys the master equation $d\rho/dt=\mathcal{D}[L]\rho$ where $\mathcal{D}[L]\rho=L\rho L^\dagger -L^\dagger L\rho/2-\rho L^\dagger L/2$.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** No. The inequality fails for example when $\rho=\mathrm{diag}(\frac23,\frac13)$ and $L=|0\rangle\langle 1|$.

It's not hard to see that the inequality is satisfied if $\rho$ is pure or maximally mixed, so let's set $\rho=\mathrm{diag}(p, q)$ where $0<p<1$ and $q=1-p$. A natural candidate for $L$ is the annihilation operator $L=|0\rangle\langle 1|$. We have
$$
\mathrm{tr}(L^\dagger L\rho^2)=\langle 1|\rho^2|1\rangle=q^2\tag1
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{tr}(L^\dagger \rho L\rho)=\langle 0|\rho|0\rangle\langle 1|\rho|1\rangle=pq\tag2
$$
so
\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}(L^\dagger L\rho^2)-\mathrm{tr}(L^\dagger \rho L\rho)=q(q-p).\tag3
\end{align}
Clearly, this expression is positive if $q>p$ and negative if $p>q$, both of which are possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not hold -- brute force numerics with random $\rho$ and $L$  finds counterexamples already for $N=2$.